# How to test a CKEditor change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, ckeditor

I'm using a `CKEditor` component from `ckeditor4-react` in my application. I'd like to create a `jest` test that will use `react-testing-library` to write some stuff inside this `CKEditor` component.

At the moment, my component contains code like:

```
const handleChange = (event: any) => {
    setBody(event.editor.getData());
};

<CKEditor
  onChange={handleChange}
  data-testid="ckeditor-textfield"
/>
```

This works fine when testing manually.

Within my Jest test, I've got the following:

```
const editorText = screen.getByTestId('ckeditor-textfield');
fireEvent.change(editorText, { target: { value: 'Email body text' } });
```

However, this doesn't work and I get an error:

> TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element by:
> [data-testid="ckeditor-textfield"]

If I try a different way to get the editor text field by doing:

```
const editorText = document.getElementsByClassName('cke_editable')[0];
```

I get the following error:

> Unable to fire a "change" event - please provide a DOM element.

How can I test the input field for a `CKEditor` component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a very elegant solution but I've initialised the `CKEditor` data when running the `jest` unit tests as such:

```
<CKEditor
   initData={ process.env.JEST_WORKER_ID !== undefined && <p>unit tests data</p> }
/>
```